# React Rendering Component React-Icons

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

How to render component based on json file information? I have a map that is rendering a UL list. Each Li is rendered. (I know i can do this with a img and than passing src={} as a object from the json file. But i wanna know if there's another way of solving this. Code below:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FiLinkedin as LinkedinIcon, FiGithub as GithubIcon } from 'react-icons/fi';

import Data from '../../socials.json';

import { Container } from './styles';

export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ul id="profile-links">
        {Data.map((social, index) => {
          return (
            <li id={social.id} key={social.id}>
              <a href={social.url} target="_BLANK" rel="noreferrer">
                <LinkedinIcon size={22} />  // change this component based on -social.icon info-
                <strong>{social.title}</strong>
                <span className="small-link">{social.slug}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is social.icon used for a finite/fixed set of icons?

Comment: i will just say that social.icon = FiLinkedin or LinkedinIcon.
e.g: "icon": "FiGithub";

Answer (score 2):

I would convert your `socials.json` into a `socials.js`. Then you can set up your data more flexibly like this:

```
import {
  FiLinkedin as LinkedinIcon,
  FiGithub as GithubIcon,
} from 'react-icons/fi';

const Data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: 'url 1',
    title: 'title 1',
    slug: 'slug 1',
    icon: LinkedinIcon,
  },
  // Other socials...
];

export default Data;
```

Then you can render these icons dynamically in your map like this:

```
// ...
import Data from '../../socials';

export default function Profile() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ul id="profile-links">
        {Data.map((social, index) => {
          return (
            <li id={social.id} key={social.id}>
              <a href={social.url} target="_BLANK" rel="noreferrer">
                <social.icon size={20} />
                <strong>{social.title}</strong>
                <span className="small-link">{social.slug}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method which will give you the icon depending on the `social.icon` value. For example:

```
const getIcon = (icon) => {
    switch(icon) {
       case A:
        return <IconA />;
       case B:
        return <IconB />;
       default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

And call this getIcon method where you need it with the `social.icon` as params.